# 4 viruses on my phone?? Is this message legit?

Tags: security, antivirus

I received a message on my phone that says, "Your browser is heavily damaged by (4) virus!" Right above that message it says Google & at the very top is www.cirplana.top. Is this legit? It says that if I do not remove virus now it will cause serious damage to my Samsung SM-S90L. 
It says this is from recent adult sites. That is not true. Not once have I ever visited an adult site.
Do I click to repair?
Thank you for your help.
[image]

Comment: No, this is not a virus, it's a phishing site. It even shows the URL on the top of the screen. Check your recently installed apps and reset your  homepage settings across all installed web browsers.

Answer (score 5):

It is phishing site, I've just had the same on my Samsung S7,
All I did was cleared my chrome browser history and closed all opened pages! Doubled check with a free Avast antivirus run a scan and nothing on my phone at all!

Answer (score 1):

It's just a phishing website and it is **totally normal** if you are seeing this.These kind of websites generally pops up when you are trying to download something (songs,apks etc) and you can't actually do a lot to get rid of these websites but if your device is rooted you can use apps like adaway to block these websites

Answer (score 1):

The Four Viruses is just a scam… Do NOT click OK and/or Repair Now.

Instead, press your Home button and then navigate to:

Apps —> Settings —> Applications —> Application Manager and then scroll down to your browser that has the offending pop-up message… most likely Chrome.

Next, follow these steps (in order):

Click Chrome, 
Click Force Stop, 
Click Storage, 
Click Manage Storage, 
Click Clear All Data

Finally, Restart your phone.

When you re-launch the Chrome browser, you will need to either login to your Google account, or click No Thanks to continue.

Comment: I think clearing Chrome's data just because you went to a dodgy website is a bit of an overreaction.

Answer (score 0):

Just say for fun.

> ## Your phone is heavily damaged by 100 viruses.

I'm saying it here. Do you believe it? Definitely no!

For the same reason, there's no point in believing that page. It's just a webpage, with tricky phishing information on it. All you need to do is close that page and (recommended-ly) clear your browser's history and cache.

In case you're still worried, you can optionally get an antivirus software with good reputation and review, though this is hardly ever useful. It's just an assurance to your mind that your phone isn't really infected.

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me so I did some research on it being really scared. I found out it is fake and a scam. If you look you will see that it does not say the site is secure as "Google" pages will, it is not a "Google" Google message.

**DO NOT DOWNLOAD THE WHAT IT TELLS YOU TO.** (Viruses could occur.) If you are still worried try clearing all history, restarting your device, and do some farther research. Just take a deep breath, your device is fine.